# I'm getting error - function sayHi() is not defined, I don't understand

Tags: javascript, html

The JavaScript function is not responding when called from the HTML body.
I keep getting the error that the function `sayHi()` is not defined.

```
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>innerHTML.html</title>

  <script type = "text/javasctipt">
      // javasctipt
      function sayHi(){
          txtName = document.getElementById("txtName");
          divOutput = document.getElementById("divOutput");

          var name = txtName.value;

          divOutput.innerHTML = "<em>" + name + "</em>";
          divOutput.innerHTML += " is very nice name.";
      }
  </script>

</head>

<body>
    <h1>Inner HTML Demo</h1>

    <form action = "">
        <fieldset>
            <label>Please type your name</label>
            <input type = "text"
                   id = "txtname" />
            <button type = "button"
                    onclick = "sayHi()" >
                Click Me
            </button>   
        </fieldset>

    </form>

    <div id = "divOutput">
        Watch this space
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have typos in the HTML. `txtname` should be `txtName`, and `text/javasctipt` should be `text/javascript`.

Answer (score 2):

Your `<script>` tag is wrong:

```
<script type = "text/javasctipt">
```

You really don't need the "type" or "language" attributes, so just use

```
<script>
```

If you feel compelled to use "type", use the correct type:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

If the "type" attribute isn't something the browser recognizes, the `<script>` content is completely and silently ignored.

Answer (score 1):

Your element's id is `'txtname'` but you want to get it like `'txtName'`.

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>innerHTML.html</title>
<script>
  
 
      function sayHi(){
         txtName = document.getElementById("txtname");
         divOutput = document.getElementById("divOutput");

         var name = txtName.value;

         divOutput.innerHTML = "<em>" + name + "</em>";
         divOutput.innerHTML += " is very nice name.";
      }
 
  </script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Inner HTML Demo</h1>

    <form action = "">
        <fieldset>
            <label>Please type your name</label>
            <input type = "text"
                   id = "txtname" />
            <button type = "button"
                    onclick='sayHi()'>
                Click Me
            </button>   
        </fieldset>

    </form>

    <div id = "divOutput">
        Watch this space
    </div>




</body>
```

Comment: Won't make a difference in this case, since the code doesn't run until the click event happens.

Comment: @Pointy Have been changed.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in type attribute of script tag. Please change it to text/javascript from text/javasctipt. It will work.